# Como evitar que o servidor / Dyno do Heroku entre em hibernação ou durma?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Queria saber como fazer para evitar que o servidor (também chamado de *Dyno*) do Heroku entre em estado de hibernação ou durma após certo período sem visitas no seu plano gratuito.

É possível evitar que um site entre nesse estado de hibernação mesmo no plano gratuito? É muito ruim ter que acessar o site pela primeira vez quando ele está nesse estado, pois o tempo de acesso nessa primeira vez fica terrivelmente lento.

**Alguma ideia de como evitar essa hibernação no plano gratuito do Heroku?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**É possível sim, no entanto não é estritamente recomendado**, pois se o Heroku faz com que o Dyno durma após algum tempo é porque isso faz parte das limitações do plano gratuito.

De acordo com [essa fonte](http://fpaladini.blogspot.com.br/2015/01/dica-como-evitar-servidor-dyno-heroku-durma.html), para evitar que o servidor Heroku durma ou entre em estado de hibernação no seu plano gratuito basta configurar algum serviço gratuito que pinga o seu site de X em X minutos.

Um desses serviços é o [UptimeRobot](http://uptimerobot.com/), que no *plano free* te dá acesso a 50 monitores e pings aos seus monitores a cada 5 minutos - **o que é mais que suficiente para o seu servidor não entrar em estado de hibernação**.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver usando o Newrelic, tem como você setar ele para dar um ping no servidor de tempos em tempos...